# formidable upload file problem - ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, formidable

I am the beginner for nodejs and facing the question about using formidable to upload file problems:

Console Output:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/var/folders/my/b9y9l2zx583b0sz5zsc63g680000gn/T/ce455bd0f3e8df772aa8aba00' -> 'C:/Users/donlam/desktop/nodejs-uploadtutorial/69.png'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'rename',
  path: '/var/folders/my/b9y9l2zx583b0sz5zsc63g680000gn/T/ce455bd0f3e8df772aa8aba00',
  dest: 'C:/Users/donlam/desktop/nodejs-uploadtutorial/69.png'
}
```

I searched some pervious case here and I try to solve it by reopen the folder, delete the package.json... But it seems not work. But I find the source file path is /var/ rather than the path I have chosen to upload. Is the problem be there?

Thank you so much.

My code

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      var oldpath = files.filetoupload.filepath;
      //var oldpath =   files.fileupload.path;
      var newpath = 'C:/Users/donlam/desktop/nodejs-uploadtutorial/' + files.filetoupload.originalFilename;
      fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
        res.end();
      });
 });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved, the destination folder really does not exist. Since the folder location is in the share drive, the C:// is wrong.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).